# Распишите эту строчку более подробно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять, что делает данная строчка:

```
print("{} {}".format(j + 1, i + 1))
```

Можете ли её расписать более примитивно и подробно? Если нужен контекст задачи, то могу отредактировать. Дайте знать.

Comment: Если более конкретно, то не понятно для чего тут фигурные скобки и что они делают.

Comment: тоже самое что и `print(j + 1, i + 1)`

Comment: @Danis Это мне и нужно было. Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3):

выводит через пробел числа `j + 1` и `i + 1`

`{}` показывает, что тут надо вставить значение переменной, указанной в качестве параметра функции `format`

т.е. в строке `"{} {}"` скобки `{}` заменяются соответствующими значениями - скобка №1 заменяется параметром №1 функции `format` - `j + 1`, а скобка №2 заменяется параметром №2 функции `format` - `i + 1`

такой вариант нужен был в питоне до появления f-строк, через который данный код можно записать так:

```
print(f"{j + 1} {i + 1}")
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Правильным оказалось:

```
print(j + 1, i + 1)
```

Comment: Смотри, но можно и иначе, но вариант в вопросе будет костыльным. Если интересно про .format(...), то есть функция f, к примеру - f"{переменная1} = {переменная2}". Эти переменные должны быть выше чем строчка с кодом. Просто помощь на будующее:D